# Testing Spring Boot MVC with autowired repositories

Tags: spring, unit-testing, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have two projects. One called `myCore` and one called `myWeb`. `myCore`contains all of the beans and repository interfaces. `myWeb` is simply a JSON api that brings in `myCore` as a dependency. When I run `myWeb` everything works fine. When I try to run unit tests against the controllers in `myWeb` the `@Autowired` repos are `null`. I need to find some way for the `@Autowired` repository interfaces to have the same value as when the application is running, or to mock those objects. Preferably I would like to know how to implement both solutions.

`myCore pom.xml`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

`myCore` context.xml

```
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.myOrg.myapp.repo.mongo" />

<mongo:db-factory id="dbfactory" host="removed"
    port="removed" dbname="removed" username="removed" password="removed" />

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="dbfactory" />
</bean>
```

repo interface:

```
public interface SiteRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Site, String>{

    void findBySomethingCustom(String somethingCustom);
}
```

In the web project:
'myWeb` pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>com.myOrg.myApp.Application</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myOrg</groupId>
        <artifactId>myCore</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

`myWeb` config:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath*:/spring/context.xml")
public class Config {}
```

`myWeb` controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("site")
public class SiteController {

    @Autowired
    private SiteRepository siteRepo;

    @RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Iterable<Site> getSites() {
        return siteRepo.findAll();
    }
}
```

And finally, the test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MockServletContext.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Config.class)
public class SiteControllerTest {
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new SiteController()).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetSites() throws Exception {
        mvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/site"));
    }
}
```

I am getting a null pointer exception in testGetSites() that indicates siteRepo is null. However, navigating to the url of that controller method executes normally.

Again, I either need that to have the value it has when the application runs normally, and/or a way to mock that object so the test can pass(or fail) normally.

**UPDATE**
Changed
`mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new SiteController()).build();`
to
`mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();`
where `wac` references

```
@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;
```

Also changed:

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {MockServletContext.class}
```

to

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = {Application.class})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe NPE is cause by `mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new SiteController())`. Javadoc says:

> This allows full control over the instantiation and initialization of
>   controllers, and their dependencies, similar to plain unit tests while
>   also making it possible to test one controller at a time.

In my interpretation it means that your are responsible for providing all dependencies (e.g. you can provide mocks etc). And since you have just created new instance without any dependencies, you got NPE.

So I see two solution:

1. Provide your own mocked dependencies
2. Use `webAppContextSetup.webAppContextSetup` instead if you want spring resolve dependecies for you.

Comment: Also worth noting that the recommendation these days is to use constructor injection instead of autowired fields. The biggest benefit I have found through adopting this approach, is that it makes it trivial to inject mocks in tests.

Comment: Perfect answer. Will also look into constructor injection.